# Assign null for the default value in @RequestParam annotation

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I use Spring Boot.

In a REST controller, is there a way when we use `@RequestParam`annotation to set *default* value to `null` for a string parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring's `@RequestParam` annotation supports:

- `required`
- `defaultValue`

So, a mapping like this ...

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{first}")
public ResponseEntity<String> doSomething(@PathVariable int first, @RequestParam(required = false) String foo) {

    // ...
}
```

... defines a request param named `foo` which is optional and for which `null` (because `null` is the unitialised state for a String object) will be provided by Spring if the caller does not pass this param.

Answer (score 0):

No need to set `null` as initial value of `String`, because `String` *default value* is already `null`, but other values can be set using `defaultValue` in `@RequestParam` annotation.

Please, find below an example of using `defaultValue`:

```
@RestController  
@RequestMapping("/home")  
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/name")
    String getName(@RequestParam(value = "person", defaultValue = "John") String personName) {  
        return "Required element of request param";  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Seems ok, but `defaultValue` does not work, still `null` / `""` values set instead of `defaultValue`. Spring-web `5.3.6`, spring boot `2.4.5`,